# Left to Right in indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a hebrew Text string in a document. And it has the wrong direction.

The Adobe docs write something about this: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/arabic-hebrew.html But I can't find any of these Buttons in Indesign CC2020.

Screenshot from the Adobe Document:

[image]

My Gui Panel:

[image]

Where is that thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says later on that *same* Adobe help doc page...

> When you install a Middle Eastern or North African version, the default typing font is set to the installation-specific language, by default. For example, if you have installed the English/Arabic-enabled version, the default typing font is set to Adobe Arabic. Similarly, if you have installed the English/Hebrew-enabled version, the default typing font is set to Adobe Hebrew (or Myriad Hebrew in Photoshop).

And at the very TOP of that Help page it ***does*** clearly state (emphasis mine):

> New and improved features for working in Arabic and Hebrew are available in the ***Middle East and North African*** edition of this software.

In other words, you need to have installed the edition which has multi-directional language support.

This is what the Adobe Help docs say about getting hold of the MENA edition through a Creative Cloud account:

> MENA (Middle East and North African languages) editions of Creative Cloud software may not appear in your Creative Cloud desktop app list due to your app's language settings. You can access MENA editions of InDesign or Illustrator by temporarily switching the language of your Creative Cloud desktop app to either Hebrew or Arabic.

There's more detail on this here:

https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/kb/access-install-hebrew-arabic-indesign-illustrator-CC.html

Typically we frown pretty clearly on tech support questions here... but I also know this specific issue is pretty confusing for a lot of people - we see this or versions of this question come up now and then.

Hopefully this is clear enough to help you help yourself from here forwards.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand that this is so deep rooted in the programm the there needs to be a language specifig app

Comment: I think I'd re-conceptualise that as: "Wow, I didn't realise Adobe was so Eurocentric and Americentric in its earliest conception of page layout and text threading that they considered non left-to-right text flows so edge-case that they developed most of their tools in such a way as to preclude these cases, and have had to address this after the fact by developing entire development forks of their tools which support multiple text directionalities; given the reading directions of Chinese and Japanese, Arabic and Hebrew, this was... shortisghted..."

Comment: This is indeed daunting. I ended up tracing the hebrew and arabic string in Illustrator because the rest of the document is is left to right. That's the result: https://kaspar-allenbach.ch/shop/andra-tutto-bene
For shame Adobe! In this day and age

Comment: Kaspar: sieht wunderbar aus - sehr gute Arbeit, mein Freund. Um fair zu Adobe zu sein, hat Affinity noch nicht einmal Unterstützung für Links-Rechts-Sprachen!